# catch connection error throw(n) from redis/index.js file

Tags: node.js, express, connection, redis, database-connection

I am connecting to redis thru heroku.

```
var redisClient = require('redis').createClient({
    host: 'http://networkinglawyer.in/home/redis',
    port: 9374,
    db: 0,
    requirepass: 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
  });
```

The redis.index.js file is `throw`ing `err` how do i catch to print it onto console?

Edit:-
Error is

```
2013-11-29T07:18:38.255695+00:00 app[web.1]: userSchema defined
2013-11-29T07:18:38.262109+00:00 app[web.1]: questionSchema defined
2013-11-29T07:18:38.264414+00:00 app[web.1]: activitySchema defined
2013-11-29T07:18:38.273814+00:00 app[web.1]: connection error: [Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]]
2013-11-29T07:18:38.282107+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-11-29T07:18:38.282867+00:00 app[web.1]:                 throw callback_err;
2013-11-29T07:18:38.282528+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/redis/index.js:563
2013-11-29T07:18:38.283575+00:00 app[web.1]:                       ^
2013-11-29T07:18:38.287475+00:00 app[web.1]:     at RedisClient.on_info_cmd (/app/node_modules/redis/index.js:371:35)
2013-1
```

Comment: Tell more about what you can see.

Comment: @hgoebl put up the error in Edit;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To catch the error and print it to the console:

```
redisClient.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log('Error ' + err);
});
```

You may also want to add handling of different forms of errors in later as well.

Comment: Yes, it is an excellent idea to place an error-handler for redisClient. In this case redisClient doesn't emit an error but only throws one due to unsufficient error handling of a callback function.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in a callback-function which is called by redis:

```
// from https://github.com/mranney/node_redis/blob/master/index.js
if (command_obj && typeof command_obj.callback === "function") {
    try {
        command_obj.callback(err);
    } catch (callback_err) {
        // if a callback throws an exception, re-throw it on a new stack so the parser can keep going
        process.nextTick(function () {
            throw callback_err;
        });
    }
}
```

The real problem is that you cannot connect to mongodb and this throws an exception in a callback function invoked by redis-client.